# Facebook Like button doesn't increment count if user includes a comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've been working on this for two days straight now. I'm using Rails 3.1.

My setup is like the one Lopez42 spelled out at the bottom of the page at Facebook I like button not working all the time

Unlike the other posts here, my like buttons appear fine, my comment box pops up and my AJAX calls return success.

The problem:

If I click the Like button and leave the comment blank, everything seems to work fine. The like count is updated (I verified at https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+url,total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count+from+link_stat+where+url=my_url&format=json)

The post to the wall says "so-and-so Liked a link".

If, however, I enter a comment, the post to Wall says "so-and-so Shared a link" and no counts get updated (as per same test URL from above).

One other thing. I have quite a few Like buttons on the same page, each with their own URL. I've tried using both HTML5 div fb-like and the fbml tag fb:like.

Also, the facebook debug lint page gives good reports on all og tags, etc.

Anyone have any ideas?

TIA, Dan